# Get events (e.g. Key up) from keyboard

Tags: c, keyboard-events, d, dmd

OK, basically I'm building a simple interactive console.

The user may enter a command `<command>+RETURN` and have it processed.

```
    while (true)
    {
        write(LGM_PROMPT);

        auto input = strip(stdin.readln());

        if (input=="exit") break; 
        else 
        {
            // Process command

        }

    }
```

However, I also want to be able to get and process other events, like "arrow up", "arrow left", etc.

How would you go about it? Can this be done with pure D code, or do I have to make use of C functions?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the platform.

On Windows, you'll need to use [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

On other systems, the terminal will generate [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for non-text input. You'd need to read them character-by-character using `getch`, then parse them appropriately.

For D, there is the [ConsoleD](https://github.com/robik/ConsoleD) project which abstracts away some platform-specific console features, although I'm not sure if it handles input as well.

Comment: The `ConsoleD` project *is* interesting. Although, I believe most of what you sent is Windows-specific.

Comment: Well most of the times you can group it in 2 as Windows & Posix, although some things might differ in the Posix group as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is a platform-specific task that takes a fair chunk of code, especially the arrow keys on linux since the input codes vary!

My terminal.d does it though for most cases https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/blob/master/terminal.d

Here's a demo usage:
http://arsdnet.net/rtinput.d

The lib has a separate event for key pressed and key released, but key released is only accurately reported on Windows (linux terminals don't tell you when the key is released), so don't rely on it unless you are sure you are doing a Windows app. But it is still there so you still have to filter it out...

edit: there's no get line function in my thing though, it feeds the events character by character. but you kinda have to if you wanna handle the arrows anyway. For a library that automatially handles line editing, if you can use GPL, check out GNU Getline, it is pretty easy to use from D too.

Comment: OK, wow. Rather impressive! I'll have a look into it! (Btw, I'm testing this on OSX (and probably *nix) - but not Windows)

Comment: I've never actually tried my code on a mac, but it should work, the terminal there I think works the same as linux's xterm.

Comment: Well, I think you're 100% right. Never noticed any difference between the 2 terminals (and I've been a user of both for many years)...

Answer (score 2):

If you need portability, ncurses is your best option. Now Ncurses can be easily compiled on Windows and there is already binding to it in Deimos...